# How to change combobox store data in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I define a combobox like this

```
{
  xtype: 'combobox',
  emptyText: 'Functions'
  store: [ 'none' ]
}
```

then, on some event the store should load new data, so I get the store from the combobox and try this:

```
oFunctionStore.loadData( ['dothis', 'dothat', 'dosomething' ] );
```

but after this, the combobox has a dropdown without any visible content, just tiny blank lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
// Change this...
oFunctionStore.loadData( ['dothis', 'dothat', 'dosomething' ] );

// to this...
oFunctionStore.loadData( [ [ 'dothis' ], [ 'dothat' ], [ 'dosomething' ] ] );
```

- The combobox implicitly creates an [`Ext.data.ArrayStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore), which will convert arrays into models.
- The `data` parameter passed to
  [`loadData`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore-method-loadData) is expected to be either an array of models, or an
  array of objects than can be converted to models (in this case, an
  array of arrays).
- On the initial store load, the original array was converted to `[ [ 'none' ] ]` behind the scenes.

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XY7BL/)

Answer (score 1):

carStore - any store for main combo.

carModelStore - store, which should be depended on selection in the carStore - based combo box

```
var carModelStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['id', 'car-model'],
        root: 'rows'
    }),
    storeId: 'car-model-store',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'carmodeldataprovider.json?car-name=lamborghini'
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});


{ xtype: 'combo', name: 'car-name', fieldLabel: 'Car', mode: 'local', store: carStore, triggerAction: 'all',
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
            var carName = records.get('car-name');  // the element selected in combo
            var carModelStore = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("car-model-store");

            carModelStore.proxy.setUrl('carmodeldataprovider.json?car-name=' + carName, false);
            carModelStore.reload();
        }
    }

}
```